# sql sum round up

Tags: sql, sum, ceil

Sql newbie here, Im stuck on a problem.

I have a recipe ingredient table, and basically what I want to do is find the price of a recipe rounded up to whole ingredients.

So I wrote this sql.

```
select recipe_id_label, recipe_name, variation_name, portion_size, menu_id, variation_name,
sum (recipe_order_ingredient_quantity * ingredient_expected_cost)
from mb.weekly_menus_recipes_ingredients
where recipe_id_label = '30943'
and portion_size = '2'
group by recipe_id_label, recipe_name, variation_name, portion_size, menu_id, variation_name
```

This is the interesting part.

```
sum (recipe_order_ingredient_quantity * ingredient_expected_cost)
```

This sql gets the right answer, as long as there are no half ingredients. If for example, you have
0,25 packet of carrots, it will not round that up to 1 pack.

So then I tried this.

```
sum (ingredient_planned_cost* ceiling (recipe_order_ingredient_quantity))
```

This did not work either. If there are two rows with half a carrot, that sql will sum each of these rows up to 1 carrot so it will count two whole carrots, instead of two halves (1).

So basically I want my code to be able to understand that half + half is whole, and understand that you need a whole even if you only use a quarter.

Comment: Use round function for SQL Server. Details: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_round.asp

Comment: There may be a problem with your data model. If this is the recipe ingredients table, why is there a recipe name in it? Is the cherry pie called "cherry pie" from the view of the cherry, but "flour cake with some cherries" from the view of the flour? Or are you using composite keys? Does the combination of recipe_id_label + recipe_name + variation_name link to a recipe variation table the ingeredients belong to? This does not look good on first glimpse and fixing this might help a lot.

Comment: Why is it possible to have the same ingeredient listed two times for a recipe? Usualy an apple pie recipe tels me I need six apples. It doesn't tell me I need 1 apple and 1 apple and 1 apple and 1 apple and 1 apple and 1 apple. What is the reason you allow the same ingredient to be listed multiple times?

Comment: Im only an employee. I have absolutely no control over how this database is set up.

Comment: If you had said "I am only a freelancer and must do what I am told", I might have agreed. But as an employee you should point out that the database is set up horribly and this should get fixed. By not doing so you cost ýour company a lot of money, because everybody dealing with the database will waste a lot of time on circumventions. Somebody must put their foot down :-)

Comment: Anyway, please explain the table. You say there can be two half carrots in the recipe. Which column represents "carrot"? I exected a column like ingredient_id or ingredient_name, but don't see anything named like that. Please tell us: What is a recipe_id_label ? What is a variation? What does portion_size refer to? Do you have the same recipe over and over, for one person, two persons, three persons, etc.? What is menu_id? Why does a recipe belong to a menu at all? Please show sample data, so we see what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you want

```
select recipe_id_label, recipe_name, portion_size, menu_id, variation_name, 
  sum(ingcost)
from (
    select recipe_id_label, recipe_name, portion_size, menu_id, 
        variation_name, 
        ceiling(sum(recipe_order_ingredient_quantity)) * ingredient_expected_cost ingcost
    from mb.weekly_menus_recipes_ingredients
    where recipe_id_label = 30943 and portion_size = 2
    group by recipe_id_label, recipe_name, portion_size, menu_id, variation_name, 
       ingridient_id, ingredient_expected_cost
) t
group by recipe_id_label, recipe_name,  portion_size, menu_id, variation_name
```

**EDIT**
Checked syntax with MySql

Comment: Really looks like you are on to something, however all Im getting is a syntax error. I think probably I don't have the authorisation to use temporary tables, as this looks to be something you need specific admin rights to do?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'. Im using metabase fyi :)

Comment: Try removing  the comment "-- hopefully you have ingredient id in a way" It may not be recognized by your DBMS. Also, do you have `ingridient_id` column in the table? Replace it with a real apppropriate column.

Comment: This is  standard sql most DBMSes will run ok. Not sure about metabase

Comment: I already did both of those things, and replaced igridient id with an actual ingredient id. And tried a few more things. Still getting the same syntax error.

Comment: Check "from mb.weekly_menus_recipes_ingredients" not sure what mb is here. Just copied from your original query.

Comment: Its supposed to be there..I appreciate all the help a lot, but I think for now I will just go for the second best solution. 

I let you know if I can get it working :)

Comment: Checked synax against MySql, eliminated double variation_name and added ingredient_expected_cost to group by. Hope it helps